# Can't set imageview from Uri

Tags: java, android

In the MainActivity I take a picture from camera as the official documentation show:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA);
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            try {
                Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
                m.invoke(null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);

                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 2);
            }
        }
    }

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Then I save the photo to the gallery:

```
private Uri galleryAddPic() {
    try{
       file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
            file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), null);
    this.sendBroadcast(new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(file)));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.v("UriTaken", Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
return Uri.fromFile(file);
}
```

Then, with putExtra, I pass to the next activity the Uri of the file.
The uri is this:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.name.myappname/files/Pictures/JPEG_20181231_002549_9133887087473873179.jpg
```

In the new activity, I retrieve the uri, and before I set the imageview with it(if I use image.setImageURI(imageUri); it works), I want to rotate the image to the exact orientation(I don't know why in the image view is always rotated).
I use this code:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        imageUri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("uri"));

       path = getPath(imageUri);

        try {
            //filePath = getFileName(path);
            ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(path);
            int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);


            Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;

            switch (orientation) {

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
                    image.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
                    break;

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 180);

                    image.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
                    break;

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 270);

                    image.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
                    break;

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:

                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                default:
                    rotatedBitmap = bitmap;

                    image.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("TAG", "-- Error in setting image");

        }
```

And here the method that cause the crash:

```
public String getPath(Uri imageUri) {

        String wholeId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(imageUri);
        String id = wholeId.split(":")[1];
        String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        // where id is equal to
        String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().
                query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        column, sel, new String[]{id}, null);

        filePath = "";

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        }

        cursor.close();

    return filePath;

}
```

On the first line of the method I got the error posted above, invalid uri: file///storage........etc
If I get the picture from gallery it works, because i get this Uri:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A97897
```

I don't know if the problem is in the method that saves the image in the MainActivity or is in the getPath() method. What I need to do is to take a picture, save to the gallery and retrieve in the next activity.